# How to check if component function have been called using Vue3, Vitest, and Vue Test Utils?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-test-utils, vitest

I have a component written in Vue 3 and script setup. Now I am trying to write a unit test for it, where I am instantiating a spy to check whether a function has been called.

I read somewhere that functions in components are closed by default, so I have to add them to the defineExpose function. I did that.

Now when I run my test, for some it's still not seen that the function is called. Does anyone know how this works?

Below is my component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import Modal from '../modal/Modal.vue'
import Button from '../button/Button.vue';
import Select from '../select/Select.vue';
import {ref} from '@vue/reactivity';
import {useI18n} from 'vue-i18n';
import DocumentDiscardModalTypes from './DocumentDiscardModal.types';
import {SelectOption} from '../../../types/utility.types';

const {t} = useI18n();

const emit = defineEmits(['model-closed', 'confirmed']);

const props = defineProps<DocumentDiscardModalTypes>();

const isDiscardDisabled = ref(true);
const selectedOption = ref({
  id: '0',
  label: t('select_an_option'),
});

function resetSelectedOption() {
  selectedOption.value = {
    id: '0',
    label: t('select_an_option'),
  };
  emit('model-closed');
}

function closeConfirmationModal() {
  emit('model-closed');
}

function handleDiscard() {
  emit('confirmed', selectedOption.value.label);
  emit('model-closed');
}

function handleChange(e: SelectOption) {
  selectedOption.value = e;
  isDiscardDisabled.value = false;
}

function getOptions() {
  return [
    {
      id: '0',
      label: t('select_an_option'),
      disabled: true,
    },
    {
      label: t('wrong_document'),
      id: '1',
    },
    {
      label: t('quality_issue'),
      id: '2',
    },
    {
      label: t('other'),
      id: '3',
    },
  ];
}

defineExpose({resetSelectedOption, handleDiscard, getOptions, closeConfirmationModal})
</script>

<template>
  <Modal
      class="discard-aab-modal"
      modal-size="medium"
      :id="id"
      @modal-close="resetSelectedOption"
      :isOpen="isOpen"
      :no-scrolling="true"
  >
    <span slot="modal-title">{{ t('discard_document') }}</span>
    <span slot="modal-content">
        <p class="modal-text">
          {{ t('discard_document_argument') }}
        </p>
        <Select
            id="status-select"
            :options="getOptions()"
            @selected="handleChange"
            :value="selectedOption"/>
      </span>
    <span slot="modal-footer" class="modal-footer">
        <Button
            id="cancel-button"
            @clicked="closeConfirmationModal"
            style-type="secondary"
            :label="t('cancel')"
            :disabled="false"/>
        <Button
            id="discard-button"
            @clicked="handleDiscard"
            style-type="primary"
            :label="t('discard')"
            :disabled="isDiscardDisabled"/>
      </span>
  </Modal>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import 'DocumentDiscardModal.styles';
</style>
```

And this is my unit test:

```
describe('DocumentDiscardModal.vue', () => {
    const documentDiscardedModelWrapper = mount(DocumentDiscardModel, {
        propsData: {
            id: 'document-discard-modal',
            isOpen: true,
        },
    });

    const getOptionsSpy = vi.spyOn(documentDiscardedModelWrapper.vm, 'getOptions');

    test('getOptions should have been called', () => {
        expect(getOptionsSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
}
```

Comment: It's called on internal instance in a template so mocking it on vm won't do anything. You couldn't mock it at all if it were called in a script instead of template. It's more straightforward to stick test the behaviour instead of implementation with composition api

Comment: Hmm, do you have an example for me? I don't fully understand what you mean.

Comment: See https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/easy-to-test.html#do-not-test-implementation-details

Comment: @EstusFlask, I rewrote my tests with your suggestion in mind. It looks way cleaner. Thanks!